# Bevels of uniform height

Tags: inkscape, shadows

I'm trying to make bevel shading using Inkscape. I have a drawing composed of multiple paths, and I wish for each of them to stand out and be shaded individually.

Before (the pink background is just background so the white parts stand out):

[image: before]

The filter Bevels -> Combined Shading does almost what I want. Here's the result of applying it:

[image: after]

The problem is that the two largest yellow shapes have a different "height" in the simulated 3D effect.

I looked into the filter editor, and though I am having a hard time grasping it fully, I think I understand that the component in charge of the "scale" of the bevel is the first one, Gaussian Blur. It evidently produces a blurred version of the path, which is used for various later stages that I haven't all gotten quite figured out yet. Importantly for me, fiddling with the slider changes the bevel height.

[image: filter editor]

The input for this component is (if I understand it correctly) the "source graphic", aka the path itself. So based on some innate property of the path, perhaps its concavity, it decides by how much the shape is to be blurred.

Here I would love to introduce a constant instead. Always blur by a set amount of pixels, just like the regular old gaussian blur dialog. That would give each path a bevel of the same height.

But I could not find a way. Randomly selecting different inputs for this component always just make the shadow part of the blur go away instead.

[Here is the file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gcrjR8ZpS6hfzsiy2vxXuNMhU81Woznm/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no global control on all the blur effects within the filter.

Most of the filters in Inkscape are made up of several SVG effects combined, so to achieve different results you will need to select the effects, and make manual adjustments to each. It will require some experimentation as the interaction between them can be quite complex.

Anyway, with a few tweaks of the controls for Gradient(1), Diffuse Lighting, Gradient(2), and Specular Lighting effects, I was able to get this:

[image]

Note: It also looks like you need to go into *Edit > Preferences*, and select *Input/Output > Rendering*, and set "Filter effects quality for display" to "Best quality". This will give much smoother bevels.

Also note: Some of these filters don't work so well in browsers. I'd suggest if the SVG is for display on the web that you don't rely on filters to achieve such effects. Simple blur effects are usually fine, but I'd avoid anything more complex than that TBH.  Obviously if you are outputing as PNG, then you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: So for clarity, did you edit the same filter that was applied to every part, or did you manually tweak a filter just for the offending yellow shape? The latter is something I prefer to avoid, as I have got a lot more drawings, some with dozens to hundreds of paths, and tweaking them all individually would not be my preferred method.

Comment: And thanks for the tips regarding rendering. I'm making icons so they'll be rasterised anyway.

Comment: I applied just one filter to all the shapes, so that when I adjusted the effects, it applied the same adjustments to all the shapes.

Comment: ...then I am puzzled how you did what you did. I understand that there's two blur effects in the filter, one for diffuse and one for specular lighting. It is that the same blur effect to the same value on different paths produces blurs of different intensities; which ends up as different perceived bevel heights. If I tweak the blur effect, then as one shape's bevel lowers to an acceptable level, another's becomes too low since it was at the right height to begin with. That's what I meant when I said I wished I could set the blur width to a constant, so it will blur the same on different paths.

Comment: @KeizerHarm Here's [the SVG](https://svgshare.com/i/Sin.svg) so you can examine the settings. Note this doesn't render well in browsers.

Comment: @KeizerHarm as I said, there's a complex interaction between the effects in a filter and results are hard to predict, and so I probably just got lucky.

Comment: Yes, it is what I have found out as well. It looks like the answer to my question (setting level of blur independent of the concavity of the thing being blurred) is no. But you showed me at least one work-around, so thank for that :)